# Data sent with PHP curl trimmed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sending some key-value strings as post data with curl. 
I found that any semicolon is removed (according to target's request log). 
But just before I send the data, it still contain semicolon. Is there any input filtering in any curl operations below?

```
function curlPostShellExec($data, $url)
{
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
    { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your semi-colons with `%3A`

Alternatively you could use `urlencode()` or as unclexo suggests `http_build_query()`

urlencode will encode your strings for safely transmitting via CURL or GET. And you can decode them on the otherside with `urldecode`

Eg.

```
urlencode(rtrim($fields_string, '&'));
```

Or you can replace your entire foreach block with:

```
$fields_string = http_build_query($data);
```

Comment: Is this an answer? You could tell him in the question's comment area. Where/how does this `%3A` come from? Why din't you suggest to use `http_build_query()` to generate URL encoded query string?

Comment: Replacing `;` with `%3A` will allow the semicolon to be curled. It's essentially escaping the character. I suppose you could also use `urlencode()`

Comment: I meant it's a single-lined answer that you could write it down as comment not as an answer.